# Show a notification only if Activity is not showing

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-service, android-asynctask

I have a background task I would like to handle. The thing is that when the task completes, I would like to call a new Activity to show the result to the user, only if my main Activity is showing, otherwise I would like to send just a notification so the user can see that the action completed, and be able to open it whenever he likes.

I was thinking of using a service to handle the start and termination of the background task and broadcast a message when it finishes, but in this case I have no option to know whether the Activity was shown or the broadcast was not processed and I should send a notification.

So this is my problem, and because my knowledge and experience in background tasks and services is limited I decided to ask for some help.

Thanks in advance for reading my case, hope for some help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a good article which describes how to implement what you want: [Activity or Notification via Ordered Broadcast](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html).

The main idea is to use ordered broadcasts. You should create a `BroadcastReceiver` which will live without any activities. In order to do that you should declare it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This receiver will show a `Notification`. Also you should register another `BroadcastReceiver` with higher priority in your main activity which will display something on the screen. Then you just need to send an ordered broadcast.

Comment: That was a possible answer I found out after posting the question and seems really good practice. The link is really helpful, thanks a lot. I think that this is the way I'll follow!

Comment: @Antonis: Can you please provide a code how we implement this?

Comment: I still don't understand this. What APIs are involved apart from the BroadcastReceivers'. What parameters go where?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this.

```
private static boolean isInForeground;

onResume(){
    isInForground = true;
}
onPause(){
   isInForground = false;
}
```

if isInForground is `true` then Activity is in Forground(Showing) otherwise not showing.

if you want to know from anywhere then add the following in MainActivity.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    onResume(){
         pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         prefEditor = prefs.edit();
         prefEditor.putBoolean("isInForeground",true);
         prefEditor.commit();
    }

    onPause(){
             pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
             prefEditor = prefs.edit();
             prefEditor.putBoolean("isInForeground", false);
             prefEditor.commit();
    }
```

Then from your service.

```
pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
if(pref.getBoolean("isInForeground", false)){
       //MainActivity is in forground

}
else{
      //not in forground
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to implement the task in a thread from a Service.  You can have a persistent static boolean in the Activity that says whether the activity is shown.  An activity is visible to the user in `onResume()` and not visible whenever `onPause()` is called.  Set the boolean to true in `onResume()` and false in `onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SharedPreferences; 
update a preferences on an activity when it is onStart() or onStop() and just verify it in you service.

Hope i will help.